# 16.10 - Ignoring update files

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, this is what shows up:

hit1,hi2,3.. blah blah blah then this

```
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Need help as soon as possible
This is happening to me after I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 from 16.04!

Comment: what is the content of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist`?

Comment: Related: [N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension](http://askubuntu.com/questions/829370/n-ignoring-file-50unattended-upgrades-ucf-dist-in-directory-etc-apt-apt-con)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a severe problem. It simply says that the file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist` is ignored because of invalid file extension. Remove the extension and it should be all OK.

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

is the command you'll run to rename it.

In my 16.04, the content of the file is some configuration options related to `apt` that control whether or not automatic package update will run and automatic cleaning of packages will occur. Here is the content of it

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

Comment: @NaiemdaLegend Has your problem got fixed?

Comment: @NaiemdaLegend Glad to hear. You can also accept the answer. That works as "Thanks" :)