# update not complete

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

when I updating with `sudo apt-get update` , I  got this:

```
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension    
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.    
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.    
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.    
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found    
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

my question is:

1. What is this error and how do I understand it.
2. What should I do to solve this problems.

Comment: rename the file from `20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist` to `20auto-upgrades` and then try again. It will work

Comment: see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/837494/ignoring-update-files

Comment: Happy to help sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is as a result of the of the file `20auto-upgrades` being named `20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist` in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` folder.

To fix it open your terminal and enter this:

```
sudo mv 20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist 20auto-upgrades
```

Then do:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Technically, what you fixed was the notice, not the error.

Comment: yes its the notice and for the remaining's i have to wait for the ppa repositories muru :)