# apt-get returning error "N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension"

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

Every time I update packages using `apt-get` i get this error code.

```
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

I think the problem arose after I used `apt-get dist-upgrade` (or maybe just `apt dist-upgrade`)

I know this question is very simular to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829370/n-ignoring-file-50unattended-upgrades-ucf-dist-in-directory-etc-apt-apt-con) only the file name is different. This doesn't seem to be affecting my machine directly but I thought I might sort it out before it grows into a bigger problem.

I'm currently running 16.04

Comment: It probably was created when updating unattended-upgrades, you may have seen a prompt about accepting  a new version of configuration files provided by the package maintainer or similar. I got it & just went ahead & deleted the file,   - see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ucf.1.html

Comment: Yes your right there was a prompt about accepting a new version of configuration files. Backed up the file and then removed it from that directory and the error message is gone.  Thanks!

Comment: @doug, could you write it as answer.