# why do I see unattended upgrades warning when installing a module?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, unattended-upgrades

when i install a module using apt-get, it installs successfully but I see the following message:

```
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

What can I do for this?

Comment: It is answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/829370/n-ignoring-file-50unattended-upgrades-ucf-dist-in-directory-etc-apt-apt-con

Answer (score 0):

You should run `gconf-cleaner` & `bleach bit` for cleaning

Also `.ucf-dist` should be removed
`sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist`